# Java - How to get the index of a given element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I have an array of contacts like so :

```
public class Application {

private Scanner input;
private Contact[] contacts;
private int ArrayNum;

public Application() {
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    contacts = new Contact[5];
    ArrayNum = 0;

}
```

And what I want to do is enter a name of someone on the contacts list and if they are found on their list return their index like so:

```
System.out.println("Who do you want to remove?");

            String name = input.nextLine();

            for(Contact c: contacts){
                if(c.getName().equals(name)){

                    //Get the index here
                }
            }
```

I tried researching this but no answer or guide seems to be very clear on this so I'm hoping that someone can explain this for me.

Thank you for looking

Comment: Use a for loop that uses a counter instead.

Comment: Do you know that beside enhanced-for-loop `for (Element el : elements)` there is also  simple for loop `for(int i=0; i<elements.lenght; i++)`? Consider using the second one.

Comment: Use a `List` that has `indexOf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop that uses a counter instead.

```
for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length, i++) {
    if(contacts[i].getName().equals(name)) {
        // do something with the index, i
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int index = 0; index < contacts.length; index++) {
    if(contacts[index].getName().equals(name)) {
        // use the index here
    }
}
```

I don't think this code snippet needs any further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a counter

System.out.println("Who do you want to remove?");

```
        String name = input.nextLine();
        int remove_index = -1;
        for(int i=0; i<contacts.length; i++){
            Contact c = contacts[i];
            if(c.getName().equals(name)){
                remove_index =i;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that may be helpful down the line is to use an [`ArrayList<Contact>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of a c-style array (`Contact[]`). This class might add more handling complexity than it's worth, but it includes a lot of useful extra methods, including an `int indexOf(<T> object)` where `<T>` is the type you specified in your declaration (i.e., `Contact` for `ArrayList<Contact> contacts`).

Answer (score -2):

Bad idea! You can't do that seriously, if you have an array. Of course you can set an index to null, but then you have to search for a null entry to reference a new contact within the array.
Note: you have an Iterator while writing

```
for(Contact c: contacts){...
```

So one option is to iterate by index, but it's a bad option. Better make your Array a Set. Then you might write:

```
for (Iterator<Contact> iter = mySet.iterator();iter.hasNext();) {
    final Contact next = iter.next();
    if(next.getName() == "NAME") {
         iter.remove();
         break;
    }
```

Always use Iterator.remove()! Otherwise you will get Exceptions earlier than you wish :D

Comment: I don't see where the OP said anything about removing items from the array... The OP wanted to get the index of an item. So this really doesn't answer anything in the question.